Use lambda in Databricks to get MoM of all the columns
I was using this code
df = df.apply(lambda x : 100 * (x - x.shift(1)) / x.shift(1))

to get the month over month % change in anaconda python & it was running successfully.
However, on the databrick this code is giving this error: 'DataFram' object has no attribute 'apply'.
Can anyone please tell me how to get this similar version on Databrick (pyspark I think)?
